# PyQt Copy folder with progress and transfer rate/speed

Tags: windows, qt, copy, pyqt5, shutil

I'd like to expand my current code with the ability to show the transfer rate/speed of the files being copied. Im working on Windows 10 with py 3.6 and Qt 5.8. Here is my code:

```
import os
import shutil
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QProgressBar, QFileDialog

class FileCopyProgress(QWidget):


    def __init__(self, parent=None, src=None, dest=None):
        super(FileCopyProgress, self).__init__()

        self.src = src
        self.dest = dest
        self.build_ui()

    def build_ui(self):

        hbox = QVBoxLayout()

        lbl_src = QLabel('Source: ' + self.src)
        lbl_dest = QLabel('Destination: ' + self.dest)
        self.pb = QProgressBar()

        self.pb.setMinimum(0)
        self.pb.setMaximum(100)
        self.pb.setValue(0)

        hbox.addWidget(lbl_src)
        hbox.addWidget(lbl_dest)
        hbox.addWidget(self.pb)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.setWindowTitle('File copy')
        self.auto_start_timer = QTimer()
        self.auto_start_timer.singleShot(2000, lambda: self.copyFilesWithProgress(self.src, self.dest, self.progress, self.copydone))
        self.show()

    def progress(self, done, total):
        progress = int(round((done/float(total))*100))

        try:
            self.pb.setValue(progress)
        except:
            pass

        app.processEvents()

    def copydone(self):
        self.pb.setValue(100)
        self.close()

    def countfiles(self, _dir):
        files = []

        if os.path.isdir(_dir):
            for path, dirs, filenames in os.walk(_dir):
                files.extend(filenames)
        return len(files)

    def makedirs(self, dest):
        if not os.path.exists(dest):
            os.makedirs(dest)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def copyFilesWithProgress(self, src, dest, callback_progress, callback_copydone):
        numFiles = self.countfiles(src)
        if numFiles > 0:
            dest = os.path.join(dest, src.replace(BASE_DIR, '').replace('\\', ''))
            print(''.join(['Destination: ', dest]))
            self.makedirs(dest)

            numCopied = 0
            for path, dirs, filenames in os.walk(src):
                for directory in dirs:
                    destDir = path.replace(src,dest)
                    self.makedirs(os.path.join(destDir, directory))
                for sfile in filenames:
                    srcFile = os.path.join(path, sfile)
                    destFile = os.path.join(path.replace(src, dest), sfile)
                    shutil.copy(srcFile, destFile)

                    numCopied += 1
                    callback_progress(numCopied, numFiles)
            callback_copydone()




BASE_DIR = 'C:\\dev'

app = QApplication([])
FileCopyProgress(src="C:\dev\pywin32-221", dest='C:\dev\copied')

# Run the app
app.exec_()
```

This code opens a gui with a progressbar showing progress while copying files. A simple label with the current transfer rate/speed (approximate) would be rlly nice :)

Unfortuanetly i can't find any examples, can someone give me a hint or maybe a working example please?

**EDIT**:
I did a remake and now I have `transfer rate`, `time elapsed` and `time remaining`. The data seems to be realistic. I have only one problem: Lets assume i have a folder/file that `time remaining` is 7 sec -> currently it starts with 7 sec and gets an update every 1 second. We expect that in the next step it would display 6 sec but instead it goes:
  5 sec
  3 sec
  1.5 sec
  1.4 sec
  1.3 sec
  1.2 sec
  1.1 sec and so on

Where is the mistake?

```
class FileCopyProgress(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, src=None, dest=None):
        super(FileCopyProgress, self).__init__()

        self.src = src
        self.dest = dest
        self.rate = "0"
        self.total_time = "0 s"
        self.time_elapsed = "0 s"
        self.time_remaining = "0 s"
        self.build_ui()

    def build_ui(self):

        hbox = QVBoxLayout()

        lbl_src = QLabel('Source: ' + self.src)
        lbl_dest = QLabel('Destination: ' + self.dest)
        self.pb = QProgressBar()
        self.lbl_rate = QLabel('Transfer rate: ' + self.rate)
        self.lbl_time_elapsed = QLabel('Time Elapsed: ' + self.time_elapsed)
        self.lbl_time_remaining = QLabel('Time Remaining: ' + self.time_remaining)

        self.pb.setMinimum(0)
        self.pb.setMaximum(100)
        self.pb.setValue(0)

        hbox.addWidget(lbl_src)
        hbox.addWidget(lbl_dest)
        hbox.addWidget(self.pb)
        hbox.addWidget(self.lbl_rate)
        hbox.addWidget(self.lbl_time_elapsed)
        hbox.addWidget(self.lbl_time_remaining)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.setWindowTitle('File copy')

        self.auto_start_timer = QTimer()
        self.auto_start_timer.singleShot(100, lambda: self.copy_files_with_progress(self.src, self.dest, self.progress, self.copy_done))

        self.copy_timer = QTimer()
        self.copy_timer.timeout.connect(lambda: self.process_informations())
        self.copy_timer.start(1000)
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def process_informations(self):

        time_elapsed_raw = time.clock() - self.start_time
        self.time_elapsed = '{:.2f} s'.format(time_elapsed_raw)
        self.lbl_time_elapsed.setText('Time Elapsed: ' + self.time_elapsed)

        # example - Total: 100 Bytes, bisher kopiert 12 Bytes/s
        time_remaining_raw = self._totalSize/self._copied
        self.time_remaining = '{:.2f} s'.format(time_remaining_raw) if time_remaining_raw < 60. else '{:.2f} min'.format(time_remaining_raw)
        self.lbl_time_remaining.setText('Time Remaining: ' + self.time_remaining)

        rate_raw = (self._copied - self._copied_tmp)/1024/1024
        self.rate = '{:.2f} MB/s'.format(rate_raw)
        self.lbl_rate.setText('Transfer rate: ' + self.rate)

        self._copied_tmp = self._copied

    def progress(self):
        self._progress = (self._copied/self._totalSize)*100

        try:
            self.pb.setValue(self._progress)
        except:
            pass

        app.processEvents()

    def get_total_size(self, src):
        return sum( os.path.getsize(os.path.join(dirpath,filename)) for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(src) for filename in filenames ) # total size of files in bytes

    def copy_done(self):
        self.pb.setValue(100)
        print("done")
        self.close()

    def make_dirs(self, dest):
        if not os.path.exists(dest):
            os.makedirs(dest)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def copy_files_with_progress(self, src, dst, callback_progress, callback_copydone, length=16*1024*1024):
        self._copied = 0
        self._copied_tmp = 0
        self._totalSize = self.get_total_size(src)

        print(''.join(['Pre Dst: ', dst]))

        dst = os.path.join(dst, src.replace(BASE_DIR, '').replace('\\', ''))

        print(''.join(['Src: ', src]))
        print(''.join(['Dst: ', dst]))
        self.make_dirs(dst)

        self.start_time = time.clock()
        for path, dirs, filenames in os.walk(src):
            for directory in dirs:
                destDir = path.replace(src, dst)
                self.make_dirs(os.path.join(destDir, directory))
            for sfile in filenames:
                srcFile = os.path.join(path, sfile)
                destFile = os.path.join(dst, sfile)
#                     destFile = os.path.join(path.replace(src, dst), sfile)

                with open(srcFile, 'rb') as fsrc:
                    with open(destFile, 'wb') as fdst:
                        while 1:
                            buf = fsrc.read(length)
                            if not buf:
                                break
                            fdst.write(buf)
                            self._copied += len(buf)
                            callback_progress()         
        try:
            self.copy_timer.stop()
        except:
            print('Error: could not stop QTimer')

        callback_copydone()
```

Comment: A simple way is to just count the files and display the progress that way, or calculate the total size and use the file size to display the progression. I guess you can't display the progression for a single large file that easily if you don't open and copy the file by yourself..

Comment: I already count the files, see method `def countfiles`. The progression works fine, I only want to show the transfer speed e.g. 15 MB /s

Comment: To display the overall transfer speed you can calculate the total file size up to the file you're copying (I guess that's not so hard if you already count them and have access to all the files in a loop) and divide that by the time used!? Or display the current speed if you only consider the last minute of files etc, depends on the file size and stuff if you don't have access to the copy of a single file it's hard to get any more precise?

Comment: I rethought the theoretical part: I only have to read the copied file size in a specific intervall -> every 1 min I check the files copied and calculate the size e.g. 50 MB in 1 min (50 MB / 60s = 0.83 MB/s) or did i miss something? But what about the intervall how can i do that??

Answer (score 0):

That's all about logic, think in the following way:

1. You have a TOTAL size of all files, let's say you have 100 dashes: [----- ... -----]
2. Now you get the starting time when you started transferring your files.
3. Choose some interval, let's have for example 2 secs.
4. So, after 2 secs see how much of the total you already transferred, in other words how much of files you already have in the new dir. Let's say you transferred 26 dashes.
5. The calc would be, 26 dashes/2secs = 13dashes per seconds.
6. Going deeper we have 26% of the content downloaded in 2 seconds since the total is 100 or 13% per second.
7. Even further we can calc also the prediction of time.
8. Total Time = 100%/13% = 7.6 secs
9. Time Elapsed = 2secs
10. Time Remaining = 7.6 - 2 = 5.6 secs

*I think you got the idea...*

**Note:** You just gotta keep verifying and remaking all these calcs in each 2 seconds, if you choose 2 secs of course, and updating the information to the user. If you wanna be even more precise or show more frequently updated information to the user just reduce that interval to let's say 0.5 secs and make the calc on top of milliseconds. It's up to you how often you update the information, that's just an overview of how to do the math. ")